# Rootcausing or working around possible AMD compiler bug

Tags: opencl

I'm learning OpenCL and I have basically ported the BSD code for crypt(3) to opencl.  The code works fine on all the Intel and nVidia platforms I have been able to test, but my fastest platform is an AMD Ellesmere (Radeon 580).  On this platform the opencl code does not compute the correct value.  I was trying to debug what was going on and discovered that merely by adding some printf's (3 printf( "\n" ); statements do the job)  the opencl code started to work.

This looks to me like perhaps the compiler has not generated the correct code and that some assignments to local variables aren't getting written before they're used.  The OpenCL memory fence functions seem to be only for writing to local or global memory and not private memory which is where the variables in question reside.

If I was on a PC, I'd look or step through at the assembler code to see what was really going on.  I don't think this is possible on OpenCL.  I'd be happy if I could construct a reliable work around (as there doesn't seem to be any particular reason why the printf calls are covering up the problem).

```
cl_int do_des(  cl_uint *                           l_out,
            cl_uint *                           r_out,
            cl_uint const                       l_in,
            cl_uint const                       r_in,
            cl_int                              count,
            __global desContext const * const   desCtx,
            cryptContext const * const          crCtx
          ) 
{ 
    <...snip...>

    while( count-- )
    {
        <...snip...>

        round = 16;
        while( round-- )
        {
            <...snip...>

            f ^= l;
            l = r;
            r = f;

            // Works on ellesmere at 3, but not at 2.
//            for( u=0; u < 4; u++ )
//                printf( "\n" );
         }
         r = l;
         l = f;
     }

     printf( "kernel f=%08x l=%08x r=%08x\n", f, l, r );

     *l_out =   desCtx->fp_maskl[0][(l >> 24) & 0xff]
              | desCtx->fp_maskl[1][(l >> 16) & 0xff]
              | desCtx->fp_maskl[2][(l >>  8) & 0xff]
              | desCtx->fp_maskl[3][(l >>  0) & 0xff]
              | desCtx->fp_maskl[4][(r >> 24) & 0xff]
              | desCtx->fp_maskl[5][(r >> 16) & 0xff]
              | desCtx->fp_maskl[6][(r >>  8) & 0xff]
              | desCtx->fp_maskl[7][(r >>  0) & 0xff];
     *r_out =   desCtx->fp_maskr[0][(l >> 24) & 0xff]
              | desCtx->fp_maskr[1][(l >> 16) & 0xff]
              | desCtx->fp_maskr[2][(l >>  8) & 0xff]
              | desCtx->fp_maskr[3][(l >>  0) & 0xff]
              | desCtx->fp_maskr[4][(r >> 24) & 0xff]
              | desCtx->fp_maskr[5][(r >> 16) & 0xff]
              | desCtx->fp_maskr[6][(r >>  8) & 0xff]
              | desCtx->fp_maskr[7][(r >>  0) & 0xff];

     printf( "kernel l_out=%08x r_out=%08x\n", *l_out, *r_out );

     <...snip....>
 }
```

Here is the output from the command line where identical code runs on the host and the device so that I can compare what's going on.

host f=2ad3fdce l=2ad3fdce r=191b13a4
host l_out=bc7907e5 r_out=bc461517

Listing 1 devices
GPU device[0] 1545 MHz 7 GiB mem (36, 3, 256) little endian Ellesmere

kernel f=2ad3fdce l=2ad3fdce r=2ad3fdce
kernel l_out=3cf30fcf r_out=3ccc3f3f

If we compare the "host" lines to the "kernel" lines we can see here that in the kernel the statements

```
    r = l;
    l = f;
```

that the assignment to "r" isn't sticking.

Comment: It is possible to output the kernel binary form and it can be depending on the vendor in human readable form. Also CodeXL should allow to inspect that intermediate form for AMD GPUs. It might be that your kernel is missing barrier(s) and that's why for faster GPU is producing wrong results but not when you put printfs that work kind of like a barrier in this specific case. But that is hard to tell without seeing the full kernel implementation. Try to add barriers instead of printf's to check if that changes anything.

Comment: As @doqtor says, it's hard to say what's going wrong from what you've posted. Also, what's your work size? The excerpt you posted doesn't look like it would work correctly with multiple work-items. Ideally, you should edit your post to include a [minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as that will make it easiest for anyone to help you and thus maximise your chances of a correct, helpful answer.

Comment: @doqtor when you say barrier are you talking about the mem_fence, read_mem_fence, write_mem_fence functions?  The documentation for these implies that these functions are for local and global memory (not the private memory used by this function...mentioned is my wall of text).  Nevetheless, I have tried adding these functions to no avail.I assumed that printf was somehow serving as a barrier.  I tried moving a big chunk of this code out into a separate function to see if that might help and I didn't see any other functions that might do the job.

Comment: @pmdj Sorry about lack of context.  I got a little aggressive cutting stuff out to distill the problem down to it's essense.  Every variable used by this function is either allocated on the stack or is global read only memory.  So, unless a work item can somehow stomp a different work-items stack, it should be safe.  And the debug output is showing not that something crazy is going on but, instead, that the swapping of the 'r', 'l', and 'f' variables isn't happening as expected.  Anyway due to this problem on AMD, I've been debugging using only a single work item.

Comment: No, I meant to use `barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE|CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE)` which stops work items execution until they all reach the same place.